# Why GVim doesn't use dark theme?

Tags: gtk, gtk3, gvim

I want to make the *interface* of GVim to use dark theme. I have the following line in my `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`:

```
[Settings]
gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme=1
```

All my GTK apps use dark theme but for some reason GVim still uses a light theme. How can I change that?

Note: When I run `gvim --version` the following line is in the result:
Huge version with GTK3 GUI. So I'm sure it's using GTK3.

Answer (score 2):

Starting `gvim` with the environment variable `GTK_THEME` explicitly set appears to work:

```
$ GTK_THEME=Adwaita:dark gvim
```

Answer (score 0):

`gvim` has several different dark themes available, but you need to tell it which one to use.

I rarely use `gvim` itself (I mostly use vim directly from the shell), but I have the following in my `~/.vimrc` for the rare occasions when I do:

```
if has("gui_running")
    colorscheme torte
    set guifont=Monospace\ 14
    set lines=49 columns=96
endif
```

Comment: I'm talking about changing the interface theme not the color scheme.